# using mysql-python only connects to my router, not my remote server

Tags: mysql-python

using python with module: MySQLdb I attempt to connect to a remote mysql server...

```
conn = mdb.connect('mysql.remotehost.com', 'username', 'password', 'database')
```

rather than try and make the connection to mysql.remotehost.com I get this error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'xx.x.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)")
```

where the xx.x.xxx.xxx is the ip address of my modem/router.  Why does this happen?  How can I get around it to actually access my remote mysql host?

Comment: I have this same problem. I specify the correct username and remote host name, and the connection uses the username but overwrites the hostname with the local machine's name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have permission to access MySQL from host xx.x.xxx.xxx. You need to grant access to the user.

Comment: but the MySQL database is not on xx.x.xxx.xxx it is on mysql.remotehost.com which does have access granted to the user.  Are you saying that the user is actually the full string 'user@xx.x.xxx.xxx'?