# _mysql.pyd module is mishandling host name

Tags: python, django, mysql-python

Note: I've seen that the person in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211932/using-mysql-python-only-connects-to-my-router-not-my-remote-server) is apparently having the same problem, but since nothing useful has appeared there in over a year, and I have more clues, I'm asking in my own way here.

---

I'm using Python 2.7.3 with Django 1.2.7 (the codebase requires an older version of Django, but I haven't reduced the version of Python. That may be causing the conflict below.)

After configuring the username to "django" and hostname to "correcthostname" in a config file, I try python manage.py runserver in the console. This results in a trace ending in this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 188, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)

_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'django'@'wronghostname.com' (using password: YES)")
```

where "wronghostname.com" is the address of my current machine. This exception seems to arise from within the _mysql.pyd module, since the Connection object is defined as

```
class Connection(_mysql.connection):
```

For some reason the `__init__` function in _mysql.connection is botching the hostname. I confirmed that args and kwargs2 contain "correcthostname" because I printed them. Apparently something inside _mysql.pyd is mishandling the host information that is going into it.

I have no idea what I can do with a *.pyd module. I guess I either need a version that handles the hostname correctly, or some equivalent solution. I thought of trying to run directly on "correcthostname.com," but it may not be possible to work directly on the machine. I've been asked to see if I can run from my own machine.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

These are two different hostnames serving two different purposes. The "correcthostname" you supply to Django is the name of the computer that's running the MySQL server. The "wronghostname.com" in the error message is the name of the client machine that tried to connect to the MySQL server. Or at least what the MySQL server thinks is the client machine name is after doing a reverse IP to name look up. These two names will only be the same if the client and server are running on the same machine.

So there's no botching of "correcthostname" by `_mysql.pyd` or anything else. It was able to successfully connect to the MySQL server running on "correcthostname", as that's what generated the "Access denied" message. If "wronghostname.com" isn't the correct name of your client machine (the one running Django) then something is wrong on the MySQL server end.

Comment: Thanks for the response. OK, I think I'm recalling correctly that this error occurred during the validation step. I could believe that one connection to the mysql db occurred, but why would the later one fail? There shouldn't be anything asking me for another login... and if it did, why would it use the same username but a different hostname?

Comment: It's using the same hostname to connect to the same MySQL server. The hostname you supply Django with is used for nothing else. It's not passed to the MySQL server, only the name of user is. The MySQL server doesn't need to be told what its own hostname is, and it figures out the hostname of the client by doing a reverse IP to hostname lookup. It then checks to see if that user name and that client hostname are authorized to connect to the server.

Comment: Thanks again, that is informative. What I'm trying to do is to locally run Django (using runserver) to connect to the database at correcthostname.com. The reason I'm doing this is that the administrator demonstrated that the client at correcthostname.com does not have the Django module. It sounds like the mysql on corecthostname.com is unwilling to do anything for anybody from wronghostname.com. Does that mean that maybe the administrator of mysql can add wronghostname.com to a list of permissible client hostnames?